# PEAR Install out of memory

Tags: php, apache, email, wamp, pear

I am trying to install PEAR into WAMP on Windows Server 2008.

When I do:

```
V:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12>php go-pear.phar
```

I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to alloca
te 91 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 91
 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried to solve the error via Googling but all I get is people saying to increase PHP memory limit. This is not the problem.

I have two php.ini files, one in Apache one in PHP. I don't know why there is two but regardless I have set the memory_limit in both to 4096MB, and I still get the error.

How can this be fixed so I can install PEAR?

---

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         V:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

So it's definitely the correct INI file.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that the memory limit is 262144 bytes, which means 256kiB.

Run `$ php --ini` to find out which ini file is really used. Then run `$ php -i | findstr memory` and see what's really configured.

Comment: It just spews out loads of info, how do I paginate it?

Comment: On Windows, just replace `grep` with `findstr`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried to solve the error via Googling but all I get is people
> saying to increase PHP memory limit. This is not the problem.

In fact, that **is** the problem that *Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted* reports.

> I have two php.ini files, one in Apache one in PHP. I don't know why there is two

Because you are not forced to have the same PHP settings in web applications and in command line applications. (PEAR belongs to the latter, BTW.) You can find the php.ini in use with the `-i` parameter:

```
php -i | more
```

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\Windows
>  Loaded
> Configuration File => **D:\DOS\PHP\php.ini**
>  Scan this dir for
> additional .ini files => (none)
>  Additional .ini files parsed =>
> (none)

> but regardless I have set the memory_limit in both to 4096MB, and I still get the error.

The [`memory_limit` directive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) accepts either an integer (which represents bytes) or a [shorthand notation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes) where you can specify other units. Allowed suffixes include:

- `K` (for Kilobytes)
- `M` (for Megabytes)
- `G` (for Gigabytes

Thus `4096MB` is not a valid setting. (In any case, 4 GB is a *huge* amount; you possibly want a few hundred MB at most.)

Comment: Sorry, MB was a typo in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

It seems one must state the memory limit in bytes.

So I just did memory_limit = 2147483648

Thanks for your input.

Comment: That's [not true](http://php.net/memory-limit). But `MB` is not a [valid suffix](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes). Perhaps you meant `M`.

Comment: I have to insist: you aren't required to enter bytes. It's documented and I've been using it for years. Perhaps 32-bit PHP simply cannot allocate as much as 4GB.